# JNDI DataSource with Tomcat 6 and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, jndi

I can't get my DataSource working with JNDI and Tomcat 6, while running it from Eclipse. I've added a context.xml to my /META-INF with the following content:

```
<Context>

<Resource name="jdbc/myDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     username="root"
     password="root"
     driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database"
     maxActive="15"
     maxIdle="7"
     validationQuery="Select 1" />
</Context>
```

And configured my Spring Bean as follows:

```
<bean id="UserDatabase" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myDB"></property>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"></property>
    <property name="cache" value="true"></property>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

I've also added this lines to my web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Connection Pool</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.Datasource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

But for some reason I still get this error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: The name jdbc is not associated to this context
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
```

I can't understand why this is not working... Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed the following and now it works:

In my context.xml completed the `Context` tag with:

```
<Context docBase="myApp" path="/myApp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:app">
```

And in the Connection URL the character `&` caused the `Cannot create resource` error, don't know why, so my URL now is like:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
```

Please note the `&amp;` int the URL...

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly you should access it as

```
<property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB"/>
```

Comment: Thanks danny, I think I'm one step closer, now I get: javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance

Answer (score 1):

In the Spring appcontext, replace your definition with:

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
      <property name="jndiName" 
                  value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB"/>    
      <property name="resourceRef" 
                  value="true" /> 
</bean>
```

Comment: Ok! I've done it, but now I get:
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance

Comment: Can you see anything in Tomcat log? Do you have the mysql driver in lib?